# codigo php que no envie los campos vacios al mail

Tags: php

¿Que codigo deberia usar para que chequee todos los campos que recibe desde el html y no envie los campos en vacios?

Aqui dejo el php que estoy usando:

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    if( $_POST['template-contactform-name'] != '' AND $_POST['template-contactform-email'] != '' AND $_POST['template-contactform-message'] != '' ) {

        $name = $_POST['template-contactform-name'];
        $phone = $_POST['template-contactform-phone'];
        $message = $_POST['template-contactform-message'];
        $email = $_POST['template-contactform-email'];
        $date = $_POST['template-contactform-date'];

        $especialidad_adef = $_POST['template-contactform-adef'];
        $medico_adef_1 = $_POST['template-contactform-adef-1-medico'];
        $medico_adef_2 = $_POST['template-contactform-adef-2-medico'];
        $medico_adef_3 = $_POST['template-contactform-adef-3-medico'];
        $medico_adef_4 = $_POST['template-contactform-adef-4-medico'];
        $medico_adef_5 = $_POST['template-contactform-adef-5-medico'];
        $medico_adef_6 = $_POST['template-contactform-adef-6-medico'];
        $medico_adef_7 = $_POST['template-contactform-adef-7-medico'];
        $medico_adef_8 = $_POST['template-contactform-adef-8-medico'];
        $medico_adef_9 = $_POST['template-contactform-adef-9-medico'];

        $especialidad_assimra = $_POST['template-contactform-assimra'];
        $medico_assimra_1 = $_POST['template-contactform-assimra-1-medico'];
        $medico_assimra_2 = $_POST['template-contactform-assimra-2-medico'];
        $medico_assimra_3 = $_POST['template-contactform-assimra-3-medico'];
        $medico_assimra_4 = $_POST['template-contactform-assimra-4-medico'];
        $medico_assimra_5 = $_POST['template-contactform-assimra-5-medico'];
        $medico_assimra_6 = $_POST['template-contactform-assimra-6-medico'];
        $medico_assimra_7 = $_POST['template-contactform-assimra-7-medico'];
        $medico_assimra_8 = $_POST['template-contactform-assimra-8-medico'];
        $medico_assimra_9 = $_POST['template-contactform-assimra-9-medico'];

        $especialidad_dibfa = $_POST['template-contactform-dibfa'];
        $medico_dibfa_1 = $_POST['template-contactform-dibfa-1-medico'];
        $medico_dibfa_2 = $_POST['template-contactform-dibfa-2-medico'];
        $medico_dibfa_3 = $_POST['template-contactform-dibfa-3-medico'];
        $medico_dibfa_4 = $_POST['template-contactform-dibfa-4-medico'];
        $medico_dibfa_5 = $_POST['template-contactform-dibfa-5-medico'];
        $medico_dibfa_6 = $_POST['template-contactform-dibfa-6-medico'];
        $medico_dibfa_7 = $_POST['template-contactform-dibfa-7-medico'];
        $medico_dibfa_8 = $_POST['template-contactform-dibfa-8-medico'];
        $medico_dibfa_9 = $_POST['template-contactform-dibfa-9-medico'];

        $especialidad_dasuten = $_POST['template-contactform-dasuten'];
        $medico_dasuten_1 = $_POST['template-contactform-dasuten-1-medico'];
        $medico_dasuten_2 = $_POST['template-contactform-dasuten-2-medico'];
        $medico_dasuten_3 = $_POST['template-contactform-dasuten-3-medico'];
        $medico_dasuten_4 = $_POST['template-contactform-dasuten-4-medico'];
        $medico_dasuten_5 = $_POST['template-contactform-dasuten-5-medico'];
        $medico_dasuten_6 = $_POST['template-contactform-dasuten-6-medico'];
        $medico_dasuten_7 = $_POST['template-contactform-dasuten-7-medico'];
        $medico_dasuten_8 = $_POST['template-contactform-dasuten-8-medico'];
        $medico_dasuten_9 = $_POST['template-contactform-dasuten-9-medico'];

        $especialidad_galeno = $_POST['template-contactform-galeno'];
        $medico_galeno_1 = $_POST['template-contactform-galeno-1-medico'];
        $medico_galeno_2 = $_POST['template-contactform-galeno-2-medico'];
        $medico_galeno_3 = $_POST['template-contactform-galeno-3-medico'];
        $medico_galeno_4 = $_POST['template-contactform-galeno-4-medico'];
        $medico_galeno_5 = $_POST['template-contactform-galeno-5-medico'];
        $medico_galeno_6 = $_POST['template-contactform-galeno-6-medico'];
        $medico_galeno_7 = $_POST['template-contactform-galeno-7-medico'];
        $medico_galeno_8 = $_POST['template-contactform-galeno-8-medico'];
        $medico_galeno_9 = $_POST['template-contactform-galeno-9-medico'];

        $especialidad_gerdana = $_POST['template-contactform-gerdana'];
        $medico_gerdana_1 = $_POST['template-contactform-gerdana-1-medico'];
        $medico_gerdana_2 = $_POST['template-contactform-gerdana-2-medico'];
        $medico_gerdana_3 = $_POST['template-contactform-gerdana-3-medico'];
        $medico_gerdana_4 = $_POST['template-contactform-gerdana-4-medico'];
        $medico_gerdana_5 = $_POST['template-contactform-gerdana-5-medico'];
        $medico_gerdana_6 = $_POST['template-contactform-gerdana-6-medico'];
        $medico_gerdana_7 = $_POST['template-contactform-gerdana-7-medico'];
        $medico_gerdana_8 = $_POST['template-contactform-gerdana-8-medico'];

        $especialidad_jerarquicos = $_POST['template-contactform-jerarquicos'];
        $medico_jerarquicos_1 = $_POST['template-contactform-jerarquicos-1-medico'];
        $medico_jerarquicos_2 = $_POST['template-contactform-jerarquicos-2-medico'];
        $medico_jerarquicos_3 = $_POST['template-contactform-jerarquicos-3-medico'];
        $medico_jerarquicos_4 = $_POST['template-contactform-jerarquicos-4-medico'];
        $medico_jerarquicos_5 = $_POST['template-contactform-jerarquicos-5-medico'];
        $medico_jerarquicos_6 = $_POST['template-contactform-jerarquicos-6-medico'];
        $medico_jerarquicos_7 = $_POST['template-contactform-jerarquicos-7-medico'];
        $medico_jerarquicos_8 = $_POST['template-contactform-jerarquicos-8-medico'];
        $medico_jerarquicos_9 = $_POST['template-contactform-jerarquicos-9-medico'];

        $especialidad_luz = $_POST['template-contactform-luz'];
        $medico_luz_1 = $_POST['template-contactform-luz-1-medico'];
        $medico_luz_2 = $_POST['template-contactform-luz-2-medico'];
        $medico_luz_3 = $_POST['template-contactform-luz-3-medico'];
        $medico_luz_4 = $_POST['template-contactform-luz-4-medico'];
        $medico_luz_5 = $_POST['template-contactform-luz-5-medico'];
        $medico_luz_6 = $_POST['template-contactform-luz-6-medico'];
        $medico_luz_7 = $_POST['template-contactform-luz-7-medico'];
        $medico_luz_8 = $_POST['template-contactform-luz-8-medico'];
        $medico_luz_9 = $_POST['template-contactform-luz-9-medico'];

        $especialidad_medicus = $_POST['template-contactform-medicus'];
        $medico_medicus_1 = $_POST['template-contactform-medicus-1-medico'];
        $medico_medicus_2 = $_POST['template-contactform-medicus-2-medico'];
        $medico_medicus_3 = $_POST['template-contactform-medicus-3-medico'];
        $medico_medicus_4 = $_POST['template-contactform-medicus-4-medico'];
        $medico_medicus_5 = $_POST['template-contactform-medicus-5-medico'];
        $medico_medicus_6 = $_POST['template-contactform-medicus-6-medico'];
        $medico_medicus_7 = $_POST['template-contactform-medicus-7-medico'];
        $medico_medicus_8 = $_POST['template-contactform-medicus-8-medico'];
        $medico_medicus_9 = $_POST['template-contactform-medicus-9-medico'];


        $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'NUEVA RESERVA DE TURNO';

        $botcheck = $_POST['template-contactform-botcheck'];

        $toemail = 'test@upttec.com';       // Your Email Address
        $toname = 'Cedma Centro Medico'; // Your Name

        if( $botcheck == '' ) {

            $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
            $mail->AddAddress( $toemail , $toname );
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            $name = isset($name) ? "Nombre: $name<br><br>" : '';
            $phone = isset($phone) ? "DNI: $phone<br><br>" : '';
            $message = isset($message) ? "Telefono: $message<br><br>" : '';
            $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
            $date = isset($date) ? "Fecha del Turno: $date<br><br>" : '';
            $especialidad_adef = isset($especialidad_adef) ? "Obra Social y Especialidad: $especialidad_adef<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_adef_1 = isset($medico_adef_1) ? "Medico: $medico_adef_1<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_adef_2 = isset($medico_adef_2) ? "Medico: $medico_adef_2<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_adef_3 = isset($medico_adef_3) ? "Medico: $medico_adef_3<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_adef_4 = isset($medico_adef_4) ? "Medico: $medico_adef_4<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_adef_5 = isset($medico_adef_5) ? "Medico: $medico_adef_5<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_adef_6 = isset($medico_adef_6) ? "Medico: $medico_adef_6<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_adef_7 = isset($medico_adef_7) ? "Medico: $medico_adef_7<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_adef_8 = isset($medico_adef_8) ? "Medico: $medico_adef_8<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_adef_9 = isset($medico_adef_9) ? "Medico: $medico_adef_9<br><br>" : '';

            $especialidad_assimra = isset($especialidad_assimra) ? "Obra Social y Especialidad: $especialidad_assimra<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_assimra_1 = isset($medico_assimra_1) ? "Medico: $medico_assimra_1<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_assimra_2 = isset($medico_assimra_2) ? "Medico: $medico_assimra_2<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_assimra_3 = isset($medico_assimra_3) ? "Medico: $medico_assimra_3<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_assimra_4 = isset($medico_assimra_4) ? "Medico: $medico_assimra_4<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_assimra_5 = isset($medico_assimra_5) ? "Medico: $medico_assimra_5<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_assimra_6 = isset($medico_assimra_6) ? "Medico: $medico_assimra_6<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_assimra_7 = isset($medico_assimra_7) ? "Medico: $medico_assimra_7<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_assimra_8 = isset($medico_assimra_8) ? "Medico: $medico_assimra_8<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_assimra_9 = isset($medico_assimra_9) ? "Medico: $medico_assimra_9<br><br>" : '';

            $especialidad_dibfa = isset($especialidad_dibfa) ? "Obra Social y Especialidad: $especialidad_dibfa<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dibfa_1 = isset($medico_dibfa_1) ? "Medico: $medico_dibfa_1<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dibfa_2 = isset($medico_dibfa_2) ? "Medico: $medico_dibfa_2<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dibfa_3 = isset($medico_dibfa_3) ? "Medico: $medico_dibfa_3<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dibfa_4 = isset($medico_dibfa_4) ? "Medico: $medico_dibfa_4<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dibfa_5 = isset($medico_dibfa_5) ? "Medico: $medico_dibfa_5<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dibfa_6 = isset($medico_dibfa_6) ? "Medico: $medico_dibfa_6<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dibfa_7 = isset($medico_dibfa_7) ? "Medico: $medico_dibfa_7<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dibfa_8 = isset($medico_dibfa_8) ? "Medico: $medico_dibfa_8<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dibfa_9 = isset($medico_dibfa_9) ? "Medico: $medico_dibfa_9<br><br>" : '';

            $especialidad_dasuten = isset($especialidad_dasuten) ? "Obra Social y Especialidad: $especialidad_dasuten<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dasuten_1 = isset($medico_dasuten_1) ? "Medico: $medico_dasuten_1<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dasuten_2 = isset($medico_dasuten_2) ? "Medico: $medico_dasuten_2<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dasuten_3 = isset($medico_dasuten_3) ? "Medico: $medico_dasuten_3<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dasuten_4 = isset($medico_dasuten_4) ? "Medico: $medico_dasuten_4<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dasuten_5 = isset($medico_dasuten_5) ? "Medico: $medico_dasuten_5<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dasuten_6 = isset($medico_dasuten_6) ? "Medico: $medico_dasuten_6<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dasuten_7 = isset($medico_dasuten_7) ? "Medico: $medico_dasuten_7<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dasuten_8 = isset($medico_dasuten_8) ? "Medico: $medico_dasuten_8<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_dasuten_9 = isset($medico_dasuten_9) ? "Medico: $medico_dasuten_9<br><br>" : '';

            $especialidad_galeno = isset($especialidad_galeno) ? "Obra Social y Especialidad: $especialidad_galeno<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_galeno_1 = isset($medico_galeno_1) ? "Medico: $medico_galeno_1<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_galeno_2 = isset($medico_galeno_2) ? "Medico: $medico_galeno_2<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_galeno_3 = isset($medico_galeno_3) ? "Medico: $medico_galeno_3<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_galeno_4 = isset($medico_galeno_4) ? "Medico: $medico_galeno_4<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_galeno_5 = isset($medico_galeno_5) ? "Medico: $medico_galeno_5<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_galeno_6 = isset($medico_galeno_6) ? "Medico: $medico_galeno_6<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_galeno_7 = isset($medico_galeno_7) ? "Medico: $medico_galeno_7<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_galeno_8 = isset($medico_galeno_8) ? "Medico: $medico_galeno_8<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_galeno_9 = isset($medico_galeno_9) ? "Medico: $medico_galeno_9<br><br>" : '';

            $especialidad_gerdana = isset($especialidad_gerdana) ? "Obra Social y Especialidad: $especialidad_gerdana<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_gerdana_1 = isset($medico_gerdana_1) ? "Medico: $medico_gerdana_1<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_gerdana_2 = isset($medico_gerdana_2) ? "Medico: $medico_gerdana_2<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_gerdana_3 = isset($medico_gerdana_3) ? "Medico: $medico_gerdana_3<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_gerdana_4 = isset($medico_gerdana_4) ? "Medico: $medico_gerdana_4<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_gerdana_5 = isset($medico_gerdana_5) ? "Medico: $medico_gerdana_5<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_gerdana_6 = isset($medico_gerdana_6) ? "Medico: $medico_gerdana_6<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_gerdana_7 = isset($medico_gerdana_7) ? "Medico: $medico_gerdana_7<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_gerdana_8 = isset($medico_gerdana_8) ? "Medico: $medico_gerdana_8<br><br>" : '';

            $especialidad_jerarquicos = isset($especialidad_jerarquicos) ? "Obra Social y Especialidad: $especialidad_jerarquicos<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_jerarquicos_1 = isset($medico_jerarquicos_1) ? "Medico: $medico_jerarquicos_1<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_jerarquicos_2 = isset($medico_jerarquicos_2) ? "Medico: $medico_jerarquicos_2<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_jerarquicos_3 = isset($medico_jerarquicos_3) ? "Medico: $medico_jerarquicos_3<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_jerarquicos_4 = isset($medico_jerarquicos_4) ? "Medico: $medico_jerarquicos_4<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_jerarquicos_5 = isset($medico_jerarquicos_5) ? "Medico: $medico_jerarquicos_5<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_jerarquicos_6 = isset($medico_jerarquicos_6) ? "Medico: $medico_jerarquicos_6<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_jerarquicos_7 = isset($medico_jerarquicos_7) ? "Medico: $medico_jerarquicos_7<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_jerarquicos_8 = isset($medico_jerarquicos_8) ? "Medico: $medico_jerarquicos_8<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_jerarquicos_9 = isset($medico_jerarquicos_9) ? "Medico: $medico_jerarquicos_9<br><br>" : '';

            $especialidad_luz = isset($especialidad_luz) ? "Obra Social y Especialidad: $especialidad_luz<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_luz_1 = isset($medico_luz_1) ? "Medico: $medico_luz_1<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_luz_2 = isset($medico_luz_2) ? "Medico: $medico_luz_2<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_luz_3 = isset($medico_luz_3) ? "Medico: $medico_luz_3<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_luz_4 = isset($medico_luz_4) ? "Medico: $medico_luz_4<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_luz_5 = isset($medico_luz_5) ? "Medico: $medico_luz_5<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_luz_6 = isset($medico_luz_6) ? "Medico: $medico_luz_6<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_luz_7 = isset($medico_luz_7) ? "Medico: $medico_luz_7<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_luz_8 = isset($medico_luz_8) ? "Medico: $medico_luz_8<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_luz_9 = isset($medico_luz_9) ? "Medico: $medico_luz_9<br><br>" : '';

            $especialidad_medicus = isset($especialidad_medicus) ? "Obra Social y Especialidad: $especialidad_medicus<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_medicus_1 = isset($medico_medicus_1) ? "Medico: $medico_medicus_1<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_medicus_2 = isset($medico_medicus_2) ? "Medico: $medico_medicus_2<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_medicus_3 = isset($medico_medicus_3) ? "Medico: $medico_medicus_3<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_medicus_4 = isset($medico_medicus_4) ? "Medico: $medico_medicus_4<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_medicus_5 = isset($medico_medicus_5) ? "Medico: $medico_medicus_5<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_medicus_6 = isset($medico_medicus_6) ? "Medico: $medico_medicus_6<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_medicus_7 = isset($medico_medicus_7) ? "Medico: $medico_medicus_7<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_medicus_8 = isset($medico_medicus_8) ? "Medico: $medico_medicus_8<br><br>" : '';
            $medico_medicus_9 = isset($medico_medicus_9) ? "Medico: $medico_medicus_9<br><br>" : '';

            $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>Este formulario fue enviado desde: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

            $body = "$name $phone $message $email $date 

            $especialidad_adef $medico_adef_1 $medico_adef_2 $medico_adef_3 $medico_adef_4 $medico_adef_5 $medico_adef_6 $medico_adef_7 $medico_adef_8 $medico_adef_9

            $especialidad_assimra $medico_assimra_1 $medico_assimra_2 $medico_assimra_3 $medico_assimra_4 $medico_assimra_5 $medico_assimra_6 $medico_assimra_7 $medico_assimra_8 $medico_assimra_9

            $especialidad_dibfa $medico_dibfa_1 $medico_dibfa_2 $medico_dibfa_3 $medico_dibfa_4 $medico_dibfa_5 $medico_dibfa_6 $medico_dibfa_7 $medico_dibfa_8 $medico_dibfa_9

            $especialidad_dasuten $medico_dasuten_1 $medico_dasuten_2 $medico_dasuten_3 $medico_dasuten_4 $medico_dasuten_5 $medico_dasuten_6 $medico_dasuten_7 $medico_dasuten_8 $medico_dasuten_9

            $especialidad_galeno $medico_galeno_1 $medico_galeno_2 $medico_galeno_3 $medico_galeno_4 $medico_galeno_5 $medico_galeno_6 $medico_galeno_7 $medico_galeno_8 $medico_galeno_9

            $especialidad_gerdana $medico_gerdana_1 $medico_gerdana_2 $medico_gerdana_3 $medico_gerdana_4 $medico_gerdana_5 $medico_gerdana_6 $medico_gerdana_7 $medico_gerdana_8

            $especialidad_jerarquicos $medico_jerarquicos_1 $medico_jerarquicos_2 $medico_jerarquicos_3 $medico_jerarquicos_4 $medico_jerarquicos_5 $medico_jerarquicos_6 $medico_jerarquicos_7 $medico_jerarquicos_8 $medico_jerarquicos_9

            $especialidad_luz $medico_luz_1 $medico_luz_2 $medico_luz_3 $medico_luz_4 $medico_luz_5 $medico_luz_6 $medico_luz_7 $medico_luz_8 $medico_luz_9

            $especialidad_medicus $medico_medicus_1 $medico_medicus_2 $medico_medicus_3 $medico_medicus_4 $medico_medicus_5 $medico_medicus_6 $medico_medicus_7 $medico_medicus_8 $medico_medicus_9

            $especialidad_medife $medico_medife_1 $medico_medife_2 $medico_medife_3 $medico_medife_4 $medico_medife_5 $medico_medife_6 $medico_medife_7 $medico_medife_8 $medico_medife_9

            $referrer";

            $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
            $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

            if( $sendEmail == true ):
                echo 'Hemos recibido <strong>correctamente</strong> su mensaje y le responderemos a la brevedad.';
            else:
                echo 'El Email <strong>no se pudo enviar</strong> debido a un error inesperado. Porfavor intente nuevamente mas tarde.<br /><br /><strong>Razon:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '';
            endif;
        } else {
            echo 'Bot <strong>Detectado</strong>.! Error.!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Porfavor <strong>vacie</strong> el formulario e intente nuevamente.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Un <strong>error inesperado</strong> ocurrio. Porfavor intente nuevamente mas tarde.';
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: ¿Que codigo deberia usar para que chequee todos los campos que recibe desde el html y no envie los campos en vacios?

Comment: Cuales son los campos vacios que recibes @Upttec? Es un formulario muy largo y cuesta verificar bien!

Comment: bueno pues es un formulario para un centro medico, el cual deben llenar con sus datos y elegir una obra social, una especialidad y un medico, pero el php me manda todos los campos, necesitaria lograr que mande solo los campos seleccionados o completados

Answer (score 3):

Usa la función [empty()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) en vez de [isset()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00e596ff1fde3a914926a14adea423628d181941)**

```
$string1 = '';

var_dump(isset($string1)); // true

var_dump(!empty($string1)); // false
```

Un ejemplo:

```
$medico_adef_1 = !empty($medico_adef_1) ? "Medico: $medico_adef_1<br><br>" : '';
```

Comment: Me parece que es la mejor opcion teniendo en cuenta que el OP dice que los campos llegan igual por ende isset siempre mostraria true!

Comment: excelente gracias por responder, lo voy a testear

Answer (score 0):

Al comentario de aldanux podría ser una opción pero te puedes ahorrar MUCHO código haciendo lo de aldanux en una sola línea, por ejemplo:

```
$medico_galeno_1 = (!empty($_POST['template-contactform-galeno-1-medico']) ? htmlentities(trim($_POST['template-contactform-galeno-1-medico'])) : '');
```

Entonces desde ahí ya sabes si está "vacío". Si no está vacío entonces guardará el valor limpiando la información para evitar código HTML ahí y que le remuevas los "espacios en blanco".

Incluso podrías hacer una sencilla variable en la que si no te es relevante mostrar nada en caso de que no llegue esta información dentro del $body (o cuerpo del mensaje del correo) sencillamente podrías poner un ciclo que vaya pasando por cada $_POST y si está el "valor" se anexe al $body, esto dado que por ejemplo parte de tus nombres son "template-contactform-galeno-X-medico" donde X es un número que podría ir avanzando.

Evita hacer código innecesario :) así tu código se verá más simple y será más rápido.

Saludos.